# autoinst and size classes like Caption, SubHead, Display, etc

Tags: fonts, pdftex, opentype, otftotfm, autoinst

Can `autoinst` handle different design sizes of the same font family / subfamily, such as Display, Regular, SubHead, and Caption?

For instance, I tried to run `autoinst` with `BulmerMTStd` that has a Display size for some subfamilies, like `BulmerMTStd-BoldItalic.otf` and `BulmerMTStd-BoldItalicDisp.otf`. If you just run `autoinst BulmerMTStd-*.otf` it will fail saying something like

```
[ERROR]     I've parsed both BulmerMTStd-BoldItalicDisp.otf
                         and BulmerMTStd-BoldItalic.otf as

            Family:     Bulmer
            Weight:     bold
            Width:      regular
            Shape:      italic
            Size:       0-0
            Smallcaps:  0
```

It doesn't see any difference between the two.

`otfinfo` doesn't give a size *range* for the two, but it does give a design size:

```
$ otfinfo --size BulmerMTStd-BoldItalic.otf                                                                                                                                                      
design size 12 pt
$ otfinfo --size BulmerMTStd-BoldItalicDisp.otf
design size 24 pt
```

Does `autoinst` have some way of merging these two, so I don't have to have two separate packages for the different sizes? If not, does it suffice to process the two sizes separately, then do the following:

- Just combine all the `.tfm`, `.vf`, `.pfb`, `.enc` files (done automatically if you maintain the same output directory, and you end up with a unified `.map` file also)
- Manually edit the `.fd` files, wherever you have an overlap between a Display and Regular series, combine the `\DeclareFontShape` commands by setting size ranges, like

  ```
  \DeclareFontShape{LY1}{Bulmer-LF}{b}{it}{
    <-> \Bulmer@@scale BulmerMTStd-BoldItalicDisp-lf-ly1
  }{}
  ```

  and

  ```
  \DeclareFontShape{LY1}{Bulmer-LF}{b}{it}{
    <-> \Bulmer@@scale BulmerMTStd-BoldItalic-lf-ly1
  }{}
  ```

  become (arbitrarily choosing 18pt, average of the two design sizes, as the cutoff)

  ```
  \DeclareFontShape{LY1}{Bulmer-LF}{b}{it}{
    <-18> \Bulmer@@scale BulmerMTStd-BoldItalic-lf-ly1
    <18-> \Bulmer@@scale BulmerMTStd-BoldItalicDisp-lf-ly1
  }{}
  ```
- Merge differences in the `.sty` files. Diffing them, I find the Display and Regular versions referenced specifically, like `\font\testfont=BulmerMTStd-Regular-osf-ot1 at \f@size pt\testfont x` to ultimately define `Bulmer@@scale` for the `.fd` files. I guess I could just pick pick one (Display or Regular) for this definition, or I could try to define two different ones, like `\Bulmer@@scale@Regular` and `\Bulmer@@scale@Display`, and edit the `.fd` files accordingly.

I'm still wondering if `autoinst` is supposed to handle this on its own -- otherwise, I guess I've outlined my approach and will have to try it now. Maybe some sage will tell me if the approach is valid. Or maybe whether the choice of `18pt` as the cutoff is a good thing to do.

Comment: Or is it wiser to just use two separate packages -- or at least, two separate families, if I can merge the `.fd` and `.sty` files in such a way?